# 413 Request Entity Too Large Even though PHP max_file_size is way bigger

Tags: php, nginx

I've got an admin panel on my site where I can upload content like images through a form. Some of these images are rather high quality and have a large-ish filesize. When I upload the bigger files, I'm getting an NGINX error 413: Request Entity Too Large.  I've tried using the php function ini_set to allow for larger file uploads, but it isn't working. I've got the limit at 200M right now, but I still can't upload a file that is only 1.6M.

Is there some other setting I need to tweak?

```
ini_set( 'upload_max_filesize' , '200M' );
ini_set( 'post_max_size', '200M');
ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '500' );
```

Comment: You need to update the nginx config as well.

Comment: Alternative solution: use something that can upload in chunks such as Plupload.